# DreamSpark (MSDNAA) Windows Product Key

Tags: windows, key, product, dreamspark

I just got a product key for Microsoft Windows 8.1 through the MSDNAA (DreamSpark) as a student.

Am I able to use this product key multiple times, on both my computers, or just once?

Comment: The license allows you to install on many computers (or maybe it's just two), but just use one installation at a time if I remember correctly. I might be wrong though and the question is better suited for your academic institutions MSDNAA administrator.

Comment: Thank you, I'llwait for other replies. Also, does this key have any specific expiration?

Comment: I think it's valid for as long as you are eligible

Comment: See https://www.dreamspark.com/Support/FAQ/#asd3 and https://www.dreamspark.com/Support/FAQ/#asd4

Answer (score 2):

**Yes** & **No**

Technically you are within your fair-use rights to activate it on multiple computers THAT BELONGS TO YOU.

Nevertheless, if you install it on more than 3-4 computers or re-activate it on the same computer multiple times (likely 3) after re-installing Windows, you will probably have trouble activating it the next time you want to.

At that stage, you might have to speak to a Microsoft Rep.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but the DreamSpark EULA clearly says "two devices". You are supposed to own both but it is not enforced.